# Store CSV into server without changing Datatype

Tags: c#, asp.net

I use a file upload control to save a CSV file into server. CSV File having a column deviceid.It has the 17 digit number like '12345678901234567' but treated as a string. Now i am using the below code to save this csv in server.

Now i open the same file from server but the same column format changed from string to number with exponential format and the last two digit treated as 0. How can i store the csv without changing datatype.

```
 string rnd_number = Convert.ToString(random.Next(1, 100000));
                            path = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fp_excel.PostedFile.FileName);

                            SaveLocation = Server.MapPath("Document" + "\\" + folder.Trim() + "\\" + rnd_number + fileExt);
                            path = "../Document/" + folder + "/" + rnd_number + fileExt;
                            ViewState["path"] = Server.MapPath(@"Document/" + folder + "/" + rnd_number + fileExt);
                            fp_excel.PostedFile.SaveAs(SaveLocation);
                            lbl_msg.Text = path;
                            update(Server.MapPath(@"Document/" + folder + "/" + rnd_number + fileExt));
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try format number to string like below

```
Dim style As String = "<style>.textmode{mso-number-format:\@;}</style>"
```

Refer : http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Export-GridView-To-Word-Excel-PDF-CSV-Formats-in-ASP.Net.aspx

Comment: Are you creating this CSV at run time?

Comment: No Just get from client system and stored in server.

Comment: Two options, while you creating the CSV you can convert number to string like this Deepu,="567890",Test. 2nd would be once you upload you may need to parse the csv and do it.